# Allow only one radio button checked in two forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two forms with one radio button for each form. How can I fix so that only one radio button can be checked at a time when multiple forms are involved?

Here are the essential parts of the two forms:

```
<form name="form1" action="http://www.my-site.com/go-here.php" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="radio1" checked="checked" /> Use form1
</form>

<form name="form2" action="http://www.my-site.com/instead-go-here.php" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="radio2" /> Use form2
</form>
```

Comment: don t you have other data to send to the action url this wat it does not make any sense.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Also what is it trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" action="http://www.my-site.com/go-here.php" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="radio1" /> Use form1
</form>

<form name="form2" action="http://www.my-site.com/instead-go-here.php" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="radio2" /> Use form2
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("[name=payment]").on("click",function(){

    $("[name=payment]").prop('checked', false)
    $(this).prop('checked', true)

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/44mycngy/